# Power Query: Identifying duplicate unique values and retaining the latest entry based on date and time

Tags: dax, powerquery, customcolumn

In a table visual, the requirement is:

| Unique ID | Date | Total |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1002 | 5/15/23 6:34 AM | 9.8 |
| 1007 | 5/15/23 6:28 AM | 6.7 |
| 1003 | 5/15/23 4:01 AM | 3.2 |
| 1009 | 5/15/23 3:16 AM | 4.4 |
| 1009 | 5/15/23 2:39 AM | 4.5 |
| 1001 | 5/15/23 12:59 AM | 9.9 |
| 1005 | 5/15/23 12:41 AM | 10 |
| 1004 | 5/15/23 12:29 AM | 7.8 |
| 1002 | 5/15/23 12:08 AM | 6.6 |
| 1009 | 5/17/23 5:40 PM | 7 |

The objective: I'm trying to identify the duplicate values in Column A (Unique ID), and retain the latest entry by Column B (Date).

The anticipated end result would look something like this:

| Unique ID | Date | Total |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1002 | 5/15/23 6:34 AM | 9.8 |
| 1007 | 5/15/23 6:28 AM | 6.7 |
| 1003 | 5/15/23 4:01 AM | 3.2 |
| 1009 | 5/15/23 3:16 AM | 4.4 |
| 1001 | 5/15/23 12:59 AM | 9.9 |
| 1005 | 5/15/23 12:41 AM | 10 |
| 1004 | 5/15/23 12:29 AM | 7.8 |

Any help is greatly appreciated.

I have tried my luck with a few conditional formulas, but to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this in M/powerquery (note sample output in question is wrong)

Right click Unique ID, group by, using operation all rows

In formula bar remove everything betweeen and including the [] brackets

Sort the data table, so _ becomes Table.Sort(_,{{"Date", Order.Descending}})

Take the first row of that (now the largest date)  so it becomes Table.FirstN(Table.Sort(_,{{"Date", Order.Descending}}),1)

Click the arrow atop the new column and expand it

~~

Total sample code, you can paste into home...advanced editor..

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(Source, {"Unique ID"}, {{"data", each Table.FirstN(Table.Sort(_,{{"Date", Order.Descending}}),1), type table }}),
#"Expanded data" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "data", {"Date", "Total"}, {"Date", "Total"}),
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Expanded data",{{"Date", type date}})
in  #"Changed Type"
```

[image]

Comment: This worked to perfection. Thanks!